# How to apply TFIDF on test set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Lets assume I have two files of text. file 1 contains the training set, which is mainly used to define the vocabulary. file 2 is the user entered words.

```
d1 = (
"Project 1 details on Machine learning",
"Project 2 detail on machine learning and statics",
"Project 3 is on mach learn as well"
)

d2 = (
"Projects related to machine learning"
)
```

Now using sklearn we find the tfidf of d1

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print( tfidf_matrix.shape)
```

Now for query d2 I want to compute the tfidf vector based on vocubarly learned from d1. What and how should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any transformer in `SKLearn`, after you `.fit` it on a train set (with `.fit_transform(d1)`, in this case) you can `transform` the test set with `tfidf_vectorizer.transform(d2)`

Answer (score 4):

you can pass the [vocabulary_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)  attribute from your first vectorizer to your second vectorizer as a parameter:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer()

vectorizer1.fit_transform(d1)
vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=vectorizer1.vocabulary_)

vectorizer2.fit_transform(d2)
```